# How to write http url based web service in netbeans?

Tags: java, web-services

How can I write a web service where I can query in the URL with some parameters and display the result in the JSON format.

For example, There is a table **AppInfo** in my database which has two columns named **AppID** and **Status**

Now, what I want is to write a web service like that

```
http://10.11.201.84?q=Select+*+from+AppInfo+where+AppID='21212'&format=json
```

So, from a user, I will take the application id and get the status using this web service. I might have to use get method for using the HTTP URL request.

Which web service I have to use in this case and how?

Comment: Did you try something ? Did you search for documentation ? I hardly believe you didn't find anything about this.

Comment: I am getting help about soap based web service which do not use query. Rather use Web service client. But I have to do it without Webservice client

Comment: just search for it, you will get a plenty of responses such as https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html   as well it depends on what framework you want to use (standalone Spring? cxf in Karaf, full J2ee?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented the necessary http url based web service by this, I have used restful web service implementation

1) Create a Java Web Project and create a servlet

2) Connect with my Oracle database (using ojdbc 6.0)

3) Taking the query as a parameter in the url (as requirement) and then process the query (I used preparedStatement)

4) Getting the result of the query and Save it to json

5) Display the successive Json data in the browser and then parse the data json data to send back the response to user.

Thanks to all who guided me !!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for REST web service instead of SOAP web service.

You should take a look to this documentation : **[Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple (assuming you're having curent NB version)

- Create a new project Java Web -> Web Application
- In the project: New -> Web Service -> RESTful service

you have multiple options.. you have an empty one, from database, etc..